# can't detect touch on CCNode - cocos2d v3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have recently started to explore cocos2d v3.0. I'm trying some basic stuff but having some trouble.

Basically I'm Subclassing a CCSprite to create Square object. After that adding the square object to  my HelloworldScene and I wanna receive touches on my Square sprite. For some reason it's not working.

Here's the code
--header file

```
#import "CCSprite.h"
@interface Square : CCSprite
@end

implementaion file

#import "Square.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"
@implementation Square
-(id)init {
    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return (nil);
    self.contentSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return self;
}
-(void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CCLOG(@"touch received");
}
@end
```

and here's the hello world `init` method

```
- (id)init
{
    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

    Square *_square = [[Square alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"background.png"];
    [_square setPosition:CGPointZero];
    [self addChild:_square];
    // done
return self;
}
```

when I run the code I can see the sprite on the screen but when I tap on it nothing happens the touch began never gets called. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not overriding the designated initializer in your `CCSprite`subclass. If you initialize the Sprite with `initWithImageNamed:` the `init` method you are implementing will never be called and touch handling will never get activated. The designated initializer you would have to override would be:

```
- (id)initWithTexture:(CCTexture *)texture rect:(CGRect)rect rotated:(BOOL)rotated;
```

That one is the only `init` method that is guaranteed to be called every time a `CCSprite` is initialized.

Either way, I would suggest turning touch handling on in the `onEnter` method, which is called when the sprite is displayed in a scene:

```
- (void)onEnter {
    [super onEnter];

    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
}
```

You can find a full tutorial on touch handling in Cocos2D 3.0 [here](https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/366/touch-handling-in-cocos2d-30).

Comment: thanks, that worked! Where can I learn more about this kinda of information, like designated initializer for other classes? - is (id)initWithTexture:(CCTexture *)texture rect:(CGRect)rect rotated:(BOOL)rotated; the only designated initializer for CCSprite?

Comment: @lionserdar : This is true in cocos2d versions 0.9 thru 2.1.x , but i dont know if this caveat still applies in 3.0. : dont forget to [super onSomething] when overriding any cocos' onSomething method ...

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Thanks, I indeed did forget to call [super onEnter];

Comment: @lionserdar Most of this is in the API Docs and in the header files. MakeGamesWithUs is working on an additional documentation that will be released soon that will cover all of these topics!

Comment: yeah I am aware of your works guys..The website is getting better everyday with new tutorials...Before I dig into the v3.0 I went over the stuff that you guys have. I think it would be better if you guys can also provide the sample finish projects at the end of a tutorial. Is the goal providing some tips and tricks? or complete tutorials? Thanks.